# Multiple tables present, add from one and disable the rest jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a shopping cart in the form of a table. I want users to add to the cart but only from a single table. So if you click an item from one table you shouldn't be able to add from the other tables.
Here is what I have

```
<table class="tableResults">
  <tr>
     <td><button class="itemButton">Add to Cart</button></td>
     <td> item1 </td>
     <td> description </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
     <td><button class="itemButton">Add to Cart</button></td>
     <td> item2 </td>
     <td> description </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
     <td><button class="itemButton">Add to Cart</button></td>
     <td> item3 </td>
     <td> description </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
     <td><button class="itemButton">Add to Cart</button></td>
     <td> item4 </td>
     <td> description </td>
 </tr>
</table>



<table class="tableResults">
    <tr>
      <td><button class="itemButton">Add to Cart</button></td>
      <td> item1 </td>
      <td> description </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><button class="itemButton">Add to Cart</button></td>
      <td> item2 </td>
      <td> description </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><button class="itemButton">Add to Cart</button></td>
      <td> item3 </td>
      <td> description </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><button class="itemButton">Add to Cart</button></td>
      <td> item4 </td>
      <td> description </td>
    </tr>
 </table>

 <div id="cart"></div>
```

And here is my jquery

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $('.itemButton').click(function(){
       var blep = $(this).parent().next().clone().text();
   $('<div>' + blep + '<div>').appendTo('#cart').after('<br>');
     $(this).closest('tr').children('td,th').addClass('added');
   });

  $('.tableResults').each(function(event) {
     if($(event.target).siblings().hasClass('added')) {
        $(".itemButton").attr('disabled', false); 
    }else {
     $(".itemButton").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
   }
});
});
```

The problem with this is that it does it on page load. I'm new to jquery and I can't seem to think of other ways to do this. Thanks.
Here is the jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/39qtskja/11/

Answer (score 0):

There is your fiddle updated : https://jsfiddle.net/39qtskja/21/

All in the `$(document).ready` is called, your event initialization and your loop.

I first changed the add of the 'added' class : `$(this).closest('tr').addClass('added');`, with that the class is on the container of you item.

I moved your loop in a function called `handleTables`; In that loop, `$(this)` reffered to the current iteration of `$('.tableResults')` so you can get the table's items with `$(this).find("tr");` and the buttons with `$(this).find(".itemButton");` and make what you want with that.